# Find $f_{x|y}(x|y)$ and $f_{y|x}(y|x)$

Tags: probability

Let $f(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
            \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}&   \text{if } x \geq 0, |y|< x; \\
             \\ 0 &  \text{otherwise.}
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Find $f_{x|y}(x|y)$ and $f_{y|x}(y|x)$

**My work**

Note $-x<y<x$

We know by definition $f_{x|y}(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_y(y)}$

I need the marginal density function $f_y$

> By definition: $f_y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}|_0^\infty=\frac{1}{2}$

But i think this is wrong. can someone help me with this part?

And for the other marginal function:

> $f_x(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}dy=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\int_{-x}^{x}dy=xe^{-x}$ Is correct this?

Comment: Those two integrals are correct.

Comment: thanks, then the marginal density function are correct. @Raptor but one question. don't suppose $f_x(x)=1$ because is a marginal density function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

$$f_y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\chi_{[|y|, +\infty)}(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{|y|}^{\infty}e^{-x}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\Bigg|_{|y|}^\infty=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|y|}$$

because $f(x,y)$ is nonzero only when $x > |y|$.

The second result is correct but you have to write the characteristic function $\chi$:

$$f_x(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\chi_{(-x,x)}(y)\,dy=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\int_{-x}^{x}dy=xe^{-x}$$

Also, the above is only valid when $x \ge 0$. It should actually be

$$f_x(x) = \begin{cases}
xe^{-x}, & x \ge 0\\
0, & x < 0
\end{cases}$$

because $f(x,y) = 0$ when $x < 0$.